# Caching Eloquent models in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've created an API using Laravel and I'm trying to find out how to cache Eloquent models. Lets take this example as one of the API endpoints `/posts` to get all the posts. Also within the method there are various filter options such as `category` and `search` and also gives the option to expand the `user`.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::active()->ordered();

    if (Input::get('category')) $posts = $posts->category(Input::get('category'));
    if (Input::get('search')) $posts = $posts->search(Input::get('search'));
    if ($this->isExpand('user')) $posts = $posts->with('user');

    $posts = $posts->paginate($this->limit);


    return $this->respondWithCollection($this->postTransformer->transformCollection($posts->all()), $posts);
}
```

I have been reading up and found in Laravel 4 you could cache a model like this

```
return Post::remember($minutes);
```

But I see this has been removed for Laravel 5.1 and now you have to cache  using the `Cache` facade, but is only retrievable by a single key string.

```
$posts = Cache::remember('posts', $minutes, function()
{
    return Post::paginate($this->limit);
});
```

As you can see, my controller method contains different options, so for the cache to be effective I would have to create a unique key for each option like `posts_cagetory_5`, `posts_search_search_term`, `posts_category_5_search_search_term_page_5` and this will clearly get ridiculous.

So either I'm not coming across the right way to do this or the Laravel cache appears to have gone backwards. What's the best solution for caching this API call?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/dwightwatson/rememberable

Comment: Which method do the API call? And die you filter on your side or does you retrieve them filtered already? If you retrieve all and filter on Client side than you can cache all and filter everytime. Ifyou retrieve them filtered than the way is to find a unique key for each request and cache this. Something like str_slug('posts_'.$category.'_'.$search).

Comment: @Gummibeer that's exactly what was already described in the OP. You can see from the example that the data is filtered before being sent to the client.

Comment: @Ben Swinburne: for me it wasn't clear which controller function it was. The old L4 Eloquent remember method did a md5 over the whole SQL query - that should be a alternative. In this case you can hash the serialized request including headers, data and so on.

Comment: The old `remember` method on database queries used a hash of the raw mySQL and the bound parameters. making a `posts.category-5` key isn't that crazy.

Comment: @BenSwinburne thanks that appears to be the only option right now. Any idea why they decided to take that out?

Comment: @stef it is kind of crazy considering how many combinations of search options there could be. I only have 3 in my example but imagine I had 10, there would be a massive amount of combinations of those options in order to generate a cache key.

Answer (score 0):

As the search is arbitrary, using a key based on the search options appears to be the only option here. I certainly don't see it as "ridiculous" to add a cache to for expensive DB search queries. I may be wrong as I came by this post looking for a solution to your exact problem. My code:

```
$itemId = 1;
$platform = Input::get('platform'); // (android|ios|web)
$cacheKey = 'item:' . $itemId . ':' . $platform;
$item = Item::find(1);
if( Cache::has($cacheKey) ) {
    $result = Cache::get($cacheKey);
} else {
    $result = $this->response->collection( $item, new ItemTransformer( $platform ) );
    Cache::tags('items')->put($cacheKey, $result, 60); // Or whatever time or caching and tagged to be able to clear the lot in one go...
}
return $result;
```

I realise that my example has less complexity but it seems to cover all the bases for me. I then use an observer to clear the cache on update.